Relative Path vs Full Path
UPDATE :
I changed some setting with your help and now I can sho the preview image but I always the same behavior.
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "diolos/assets/images/diolosLogoBlancEntete.png".
Exception: Asset not found


New pubspec.yaml
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - diolos/assets/images/

Flutter doctor

Previous Answer
With Visual Studio Code, I can't use relative path for all assets. I must use the full path to show any asset images. When I'm using a relative path, the image doesn't appear.
Do you know how to use relative paths in Visual Studio?
pubspec.yaml
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
assets:
  - diolos/assets/images/

When I link an imagem I must add the full path.
Image.asset(
height: 50,
"/Users/ogosselin/Documents/Projets/AppMobile/diolos/assets/images/diolosLogoVioletEntete.png"),

Image doesn't appear with a relative path, but it works with the full path.

Could you also add and example of  how you call Image.asset using a relative path?

I always this error but the preview works fine : The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "assets/images/diolosLogoBlancEntete.png".
Exception: Asset not found

Have you corrected the entry diolos/assets/images/ -> assets/images/ in your pubspec.yaml like suggested below?

Yes, I have the preview image on the left in visual suction code. It's good but when I launch the App I Always an error Code. For this example I have the preview but If I don't add path diolos/ I don't have the preview. But the behavior is the same. Same error :
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "diolos/assets/images/diolosLogoBlancEntete.png".
Exception: Asset not found

It is not clear why you are still using Image.asset("diolos/assets/images/...") instead of Image.asset("assets/images/...)?

Because it's the same behavior with or not. Result with only assets/images. The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "assets/images/diolosLogoBlancEntete.png".
Exception: Asset not found

First of all your assets folder will look like this:
project_name
├── assets
│   └── images
│       └── diolosLogoVioletEntete.png
├── android
├── ios
├── lib
└── pubspec.yaml

Then in your pubspec.yaml file add assets like this:
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/

And use it like this:
Image.asset('assets/images/diolosLogoVioletEntete.png')


same error : The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "assets/images/diolosLogoBlancEntete.png".
Exception: Asset not found

Okay. Make sure in pubspec.yaml file in the flutter package assets: tag must be correctly indented with the flutter: tag. See my answer I have indented correctly and I can see that in your question you have not correctly indented. Just give 2 spaces before assets.

Yes, indend good. I have the preview of file image good on Visual studio code. I don't understand why I always an error path when I launch the APP. flutter doctor -v is good as well

Then can you edit your question and can you share folder structure image and pubspec.yaml image where assets mentioned?

Done. Thank you

@Olivier Where was the problem?

Asset it's not loaded with error : The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: "diolos/assets/images/diolosLogoBlancEntete.png".
Exception: Asset not found

It looks like diolos is your project name, so the path to the assets folder in the pubspec.yaml file should be:
assets:
    - assets/images/



open vs code right click on asset and click copy relative path and then paste this in pubspec.yaml file.

Same. Images doesn't appear if I do that
